# Uriinfo for PUT method

Tags: jersey

I am using Urinfo for accessing query parameters in my restful web service as follows

```
@GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/association")   
    public Response Association(            
            @Context UriInfo uriInfo){      
            String clinicianId = uriInfo.getQueryParameters().getFirst("clinicianId");
            List<String> providerList = uriInfo.getQueryParameters().get("clinicialProviderId");
```

How to access Parameters for **PUT** metod using uriinfo.

Answer (score 1):

The same way.

Perhaps I don't understand the question. Query parameters are accessed the same way regardless of the HTTP method. Are you talking about different parameters for PUT? Do you mean Form fields? If you are sending form data in your PUT request and you want to access that, you can use @FormParam to inject them into your method parameters or fields. Btw, there is also @QueryParam you can use to inject query parameters instead of using UriInfo.

Comment: Is it possible to access Form Param using UriInfo?

Comment: No. Form params are part of the message entity, not part of the URI. Another way to access Form params is to add parameter of type Form into your PUT method and then calling form.get("param-name") to get a parameter value. Like this: `@PUT public Response putSomething(Form myForm)` and then `myForm.get("foo")` or `myForm.getFirst("foo")`.